# Angular data binding not allowing to get latest data in a object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

In my Angular controller on top I have an object:

```
$scope.options = {
    name:'someValue',
    data: $scope.user,
    mode: 'create'
}
```

In this object, you can see I have a `$scope.user` value.

**What I am doing**

I am using `$scope.options` object in my controller in different functions like this:

```
$scope.saveUser = function(){
  userService.save($scope.options); // $scope.options.data contains $scope.user
}
```

**What is the problem**

If I update the values in HTML fields the `$scope.user` got change but in `$scope.saveUser` I am not getting the updated values in `$scope.user`. For example, if I do something:

```
$scope.saveUser = function(){
  console.log("The $scope.user is :", $scope.user); // gives updated data
  console.log("The $scope.options.data is :", $scope.options.data); // don't give updated data
  userService.save($scope.options);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be binding the scope of options inside the saveUser function as below

```
var bindData =function(){
     $scope.options = {
          name:'someValue',
          data: $scope.user,
          mode: 'create'
  }
}

$scope.saveUser = function(){
  bindData();
  console.log("The $scope.user is :", $scope.user); // gives updated data
  console.log("The $scope.options.data is :", $scope.options.data); // don't give updated data
  userService.save($scope.options);
}
```

Comment: I have multiple functions and I don't want to repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use watch.

`$scope.$watch('user', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
    //Do anything with 
    $scope.options.data= $scope.user;
}, true);`

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
$scope.options = {
    data: function(){ return $scope.user; }
}

$scope.saveUser = function(){
    console.log("The $scope.options.data is :", $scope.options.data()); 
}
```

But rather than creating the user object as a sibling to $scope.options – why not simply link it directly to the data property – like:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="options.data.user.name" />
 <input type="email" ng-model="options.data.user.email" />
```

... defining data as an empty opject

```
 $scope.options = {
     data: {}
 }
```